# Linq generated sql request "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I have "table or view does not exist" exception when I send my sql request.
How can I remove " "dbo". " from my sql request to make it work?

Exception :

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL:

```
SELECT 
 CAST( "Extent1"."COM_CHRONO" AS number(10,0)) AS "C1", 
"Extent1"."SER_CODE" AS "SER_CODE", 
"Extent1"."REP_NOM" AS "REP_NOM", 
"Extent1"."COM_COMMENTAIRE" AS "COM_COMMENTAIRE", 
FROM "dbo"."COMMANDE" "Extent1"
```

linq:

```
var sel = from c in ctx.Orders 
          select c;
```

Comment: Just remove "dbo.". You need to find out where `COMMANDE` table is created, if its in current schema, use `COMMANDE` directly, if it is in some other schema, use `schema.table_name` to access, but make sure that the current schema has appropriate grants on that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you are using Code-First or Database-First approach.

If Code-First approach is your case, then you have to specify `Schema` for the `Table` attribute like this:

```
[Table("TableName", Schema="MySchema")]
public class SomeClassName {
    ...
}
```

If you're using the latter approach, then you have to change `Database Schema Name` property of your EntityModel (by default it is 'dbo'). Just select your EDMX file in 'Solution Explorer' and check it's properties.